# Open source applications using apache mahout algorithms

Tags: apache, hadoop, machine-learning, mahout

I'm working on a project using hadoop. Now I want to test a data intensive application on the hadoop.I checked out apache mahout machine learning algorithms.Are there any open source applications running over hadoop using apahce mahout machine learning algorithms?

Comment: Mahout itself is a data-intensive app. Are you sure you don't just want Mahout?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by watching official Mahout page - [Powered by Mahout](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Powered+By+Mahout) where you can find a list of commercial and academic uses of the Mahout software. I guess some of them should be open sourced but haven't checked myself.